# Can not ping from specific vlan tagging interface

Tags: centos, vlan, iproute2, trunk

On my box I have following interfaces(vlan tagging):

eth2.556: 172.16.1.17

eth2.201: 192.168.208.143

All default route via 172.16.1.1

I can ping all other IP using 192.168.208.x, but can not ping outside IP from source 192.168.204.143.

In tcpdump, i can not see any packet that my box send out, although I can receive packet on eth2.201 from outside

My box running CentOS 6.x with OpenVZ Kernel, all rp_filter was off.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a route between these two subnets? The 192.x subnet needs a route to your 172.x subnet and vice versa. Also if both VLANs would be in the same range you need also a route, because the interfaces works in different separate VLANs without routing - the devices will ignore each other.

Comment: What you mean "tour", two subnet can ping each them.

Comment: (orr this real creepy autocomplete on my phone kills me) let me correct this above